# How to add translations to database after API response with EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have a requirement to add a project and translate its description with an external API translation service into several languages (so they exist in the database and it's possible to fetch a project in different languages later). Since translation takes quite some time - I first need to return the API response and then translate description and add additional locale rows to the database.
The db schema looks like this:
[image]
DB Context setup:

```
public class ProjectsContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectsContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
        mb.Entity<ProjectLocale>().ToTable("ProjectLocales")
            .HasKey(pl => new {pl.ProjectId, pl.Locale});
    }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Startup` class, `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectsContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(envConfig.PROJECTS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING_MASTER));
```

The models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public List<ProjectLocale> ProjectLocales { get; private set; } = new List<ProjectLocale>();
    public async Task TranslateDescription(Translator translator, LanguageEnum currentLanguage)
    {
        ProjectLocales = await translator.Translate(ProjectLocales, currentLanguage);
    }
}
public class ProjectLocale
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In the repository I have the following `Add` and `AddProjectDescriptionTranslation` methods:

```
public void Add(Project project)
{
    projectsContext.Projects.Add(project);
    projectsContext.SaveChanges();
    AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(project);
}

private async Task AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(Project project)
{
    await project.TranslateDescription(translator, headers.LanguageEnum);
    projectsContext.Projects.Update(project);
    projectsContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I use `Add` method in the controller's POST method, and the next row is already returning the added project with the description in the current language. Translator and Headers are injected into my repository class.
The current solution gives me an error (that I can view only if I follow the async method execution with a breakpoint):

```
Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was
resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance
elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context,
or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should
let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'ProjectsContext'.
```

Is there any solution to this problem? Or maybe a better approach to achieve the same goal? I need the translations to be saved in the database after the response is given to the user in the current language (I receive the current language project's description from the frontend) to optimize the response time.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: you added your context as `Scoped` which will be thrown away after you return the result. My suggestion would be to use a `Queue` service / background worker process with `IHostedService` / `.Net Channel`. if you are using microservices and want to achieve stateless then going for queue would be a better choice, if you are sure of a single instance always then can probably go with  simpler choice of doing as a background task with IHostedService or any plugin like Hangfire. Or you can check about .Net Channel. I havent personally played with it yet, i think its similar to a queue service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not sure if it's the best approach but I was able to solve it the following way:
Added another constructor for `ProjectContext` and `OnConfiguring` method:

```
public ProjectsContext(string connectionString)
{
    this.connectionString = connectionString;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (connectionString != null)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Added `ProjectContextFactory`:

```
public class ProjectsContextFactory
{
    private readonly EnvConfig envConfig;

    public ProjectsContextFactory(IOptions<EnvConfig> envConfig)
    {
        this.envConfig = envConfig.Value;
    }

    public ProjectsContext CreateProjectsContext()
    {
        return new ProjectsContext(envConfig.PROJECTS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING_MASTER);
    }
}
```

Made the following changes in Add and AddTranslations methods:

```
public void Add(Project project)
{
    projectsContext.Projects.Add(project);
    projectsContext.SaveChanges();
    AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(project);
}

private async Task AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(Project project)
{
    using (var context = projectsContextFactory.CreateProjectsContext())
    {
        context.Attach(project);
        await project.TranslateDescription(translator, headers.LanguageEnum);
        context.Projects.Update(project);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It allows me to save the project with the current language description and return API response before the description gets translated into other languages and gets saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It hard to say what you trying to achieve and how you are doing it, so this answer might be useless. I am not sure how you are disposing the context, but you have to make sure you dispose it after all the calls are made.

the most straightforward approach it to have

```
public async Task Add(Project project)
{
    using (var projectsContext= new ProjectsContext())
    {     
        // Perform data access using the context
    
        projectsContext.Projects.Add(project);
        projectsContext.SaveChanges();
        await AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(project, projectsContext);
     }
   }
}

private async Task AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(Project project, ProjectsContext projectsContext)
{
    await project.TranslateDescription(translator, headers.LanguageEnum);
    projectsContext.Projects.Update(project);
    projectsContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi :) The db context's life (as far as I understand) is managed by IoC container. The problem with your example is that we await execution of the translate method and therefore block the thread and do not return the API response until all the translations areready and inserted in the database. The execution time is too high to make people wait for it to be completed. Therefore, the solution I tried to implement is to insert the project info in current language and then init another thread (since AddProjectDescriptionTranslations is async and not awaited) for translation and insertion into db

Comment: Well you are not doing it properly to begin with, you cannot call async method without doing await like  AddProjectDescriptionTranslations(project); it might have several issues it will never excute or it will try to execute while contxt already disposed

Comment: Indeed, context is disposed, that's the exception I get. Maybe you got an idea about how could achieve that? Some best practice for the case when you need to continue to work with the context after API response is returned?